# AWS IAM instance policy applying credentials to instance in one region, but not another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a setup where I launch AWS EC2 instances from templates and their AMI contains the AWS CLI, so it can copy over the contents of a private S3 bucket on launch. This template automatically applies an IAM role with the "AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess" policy. This has been working as intended so far in the eu-west-2 region, but now I wanted to run these instances in us-east-2 region. I copied the AMI and made a new template using identical settings to the ones in eu-west-2, but when the script to sync the S3 buckets launches (it's just a bat file that runs "aws s3 sync ... ...") the contents of the synced folder are empty.

After a bit of looking around I noticed that it throws a "fatal error: Unable to locate credentials" error. I checked the credentials using "aws configure list" and get that access_key, secret_key and region are not set. If I run the same instance back in eu-west-2 these fields are populated.

[image: aws configure list]

I've tried recopying the base AMI, recreating the launch templates, creating region specific buckets, creating new IAM policies and all this as both a IAM user and the root user, the credentials still get set in eu-west-2, but not us-east-2.
The only configurations that differ are the VPC, subnet and routing table settings - for obvious reasons, as they need to be in a new region.
Does anybody know why this might be happening? As I've run out of ideas.

us-east-2a instance
[image: us-east-2a instance]

us-east-2b instance
[image: us-east-2b instance]

Comment: check whether your instance in us-east-2 is attached with Iam role that with correct permission or not

Comment: It is attached with the same role as the instances in eu-west-2. So yes - with the correct permissions to access S3.

Comment: @Shumas - I don't think your answer does make much sense. IAM is a global service, so any role created is global. But roles cannot be really attached to instances. You attach Instance Profiles to instances. `aws configure list` is nice, but what actually happens it that it checks the instance metadata. You should be able to download the access key from the metadata https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html can you check that you can read iam/security-credentials/role-name and the credentials?

Comment: @petrch I know that IAM roles/policies are global, that's why this issue was so confusing.  If I log into an instance created from the template in us-east-2a, then I can read the role name and credentials from the metadata (I can also see it `aws configure list`), if I run the same template on us-east-2b I can't access the credentials and cli list is not-set.
I've made screenshots (I'll be taking down these instances immediately), to show that at least the web console shows, that both instances should get the settings applies through IAM role.

Comment: @Shumas the only way I can see the instances can be affected by the subnets is if the subnets are not in the same vpc or the dhcp options for those subnets are somehow misconfigured, but I think the metadata would still work.

Comment: @petrch As I said, the whole situation just seems very odd. I imagine the instances being on different VPCs shouldn't really affect the instances either as both IAM settings and S3 buckets are globally accessible (unless modified by specific policies, obviously). Either way this shouldn't be the case here as there is only one VPC in that region and all network settings (VPC, Subnet, DHCP, gateway, etc.) are the default ones provided by AWS.

Comment: What sounds really strange to me is that you say that you were able to verify that the instance profile credentials are available in the metadata and you can manually copy & paste the api key and the secret key to your command line and you still cannot use the permissions of that profile. Did you test that? Also, do you have by any chance aws cli version 1? Can you upgrade to version 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as I was continuing to have issues with the copied AMI, I decided to just build one from scratch on the us-east-2 server.

I made a new instance, set it up, and created a new AMI. When I launched it the instance policy applied correctly and everything worked. When I made a template from the AMI, however, everything the credentials were missing again. I tried launching the instance from the AMI (not the template) everything worked again. I compared the settings between the template and AMI launched instances and the only difference (besides different IP's and such) was the subnet - the working AMI image was on us-east-2a, the template created instance was on us-east-2b. Now this seems odd to me, that policy applied credentials would be subnet dependent, but as much as I tested this seems to be the case.

**TL;DR**. Policy set credentials were not being applied due to new images not being launched on same subnet as to where the original AMI was built on(us-east-2a and us-east-2b). Solved by setting launch template to use same subnet.